# How to periodically update a table in Postgresql via data retrieved from a php API using cronjob?

Tags: postgresql, api, cron, cron-task

I have a database in `PostgreSQL` in which few tables are supposed to be regularly updated. The data is retrieved from an external API written in `PHP`.

Basically the idea is to update a table related to meteo data everyday by the data collected from a meteo station. My primary idea is to do this job by using `cron` which will automatically update the data. In this case I probably need to write a `cronjob` in the form of a script and then run it in the server.

Being a newbie I find it little difficult to deal with. Please suggest me the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty much as you described and does not get any more simple.

You have to:

1. Write a client script (possibly in `PHP`) that will pull data from the remote API. You can use `CURL` extension or whatever you like.
2. Make the client script update the tables. Consider saving history, not just overwriting current values.
3. Make the client script log it's operation properly. You will need to know how it does once deployed to production.
4. Test that your script successfully runs on server.
5. Add (or ask your server admin to add) a line to the `crontab` that will execute your script.
6. PROFIT! :)

Good luck!